# Streaming mp4 file on https

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

i'm stuck with something and i couldn't find any solution, i have this code:

```
    private void GetFileFromURL(string url,NetworkCredential cred)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                if (cred != null)
                {
                    //client.Credentials = cred;
                }
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                        {
                            //byte[] buf = new byte[500024];
                            byte[] buf = new byte[500024];
                            count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 500024);
                            StreamToClient(buf, count);
                        }
                        else
                            break;

                    } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    bool isHeaderSent = false;
    private void StreamToClient(byte[] bytes,int length)
    {
        if (!isHeaderSent)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = false;

            Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";

            isHeaderSent = true;
        }
        Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
```

this code lays at getVideo.aspx.cs  and the code i use for streaming my mp4 file, it works great on http, but when i change it to https (on iis), i get nothing on my client, at client side i use this :

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videoSource;

where videoSource is something like : https:// localhost /getVideo.aspx

from what i was reading on google it might be something with the headers, something about adding special headers when using https, but not sure if its relevance.

ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okis, i write this for anyone else who has the same problem :

Https has a shorter time window for response, therefor, you must tell the client how long your data is so the client won't think that the stream is over, what you actually need to add is those headers :

```
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=video.mp4");

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", totalBytes.ToString());
```

where totalBytes is a long that holds the amount of bytes in the file, you need to get it from the server before you send the file to the client.